# Finding coefficients of some polynomials

Tags: factoring

Assume we know $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ of degree at least $4$ and we also know $r\in\Bbb Z$.

How do we find $\alpha(x),\beta(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ of any degree and $g(x),h(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that
$$f(x)=(g(x)+\alpha(x) x(x-r))(h(x)+\beta(x) x(x-r))?$$

I need $deg(g(x)),deg(h(x))\geq2$.

Can we use LLL?

Comment: What is LLL? Explain please.

Comment: Still, $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ be any polynomials, $g(x)=1-\alpha(x)x(x-r)$ and $h(x)=f(x)-\beta(x)x(x-r)$

Comment: g,h equal degrees